# What's the language and redirect inputs mean in the form?

Tags: html, forms

When I am reading code in browser:

```
<div class="login-body">
    <h2>Please type your password</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/admin/dologin.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="language" id="inputLanguage" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/admin/" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
```

`redirect` in the form's function, whether when I write a custom form, this input will write too?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. See [MDN’s article on `<input type="hidden">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).

Comment: Just wild guess what you are asking ...  name attr can vary. In this case name="redirect" . So when Form is Submitted. Variable is added with like this "redirect" : "value of Variable". You can change this variable name to anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just submitting the form to `/admin/dologin.php`, with one field with the name of `redirect` and value as `/admin/`

If you check the code of `/admin/dologin.php`, there must be some if statement working on the `$_POST['redirect']`, which is a post superglobal, and has a value `/admin/`

This form will always submit this value since it is hardcoded and is hidden so no one can change it explicitly.

I Hope this clears your doubt!